# Compiling an IronPython code to EXE or DLL

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ironpython

Can I compile an IronPython code to EXE or DLL in a .NET runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a .NET assembly in IronPython and call it from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561509/how-do-i-create-a-net-assembly-in-ironpython-and-call-it-from-c)

Comment: The duplicate question is a year and a half old, and we have dynamic types in C# now.  Let's keep this question open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `clr.CompileModules` in an IronPython script to convert it to a dll file.
Or you can use `pyc.py` (found inside of your `IronPythonInstallDirectory\Tools\Scripts`) which can also generate an exe for you also.

Comment: After we obtained the dll how do we use it? ScriptEngine don't have an option to crate scope from dll.

Answer (score 1):

If I really, really needed that I would create a wrapper DLL/EXE in another language. The Python code can then be stored as a resource in the DLL that is loaded when the assembly is first accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! I posted a Python script which can take an IronPython file, figure out its dependencies and compile the lot into a standalone binary at [Ironpython 2.6 .py -> .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578010/ironpython-2-6-py-exe/9609120#9609120). Hope you find it useful.