# Can I compile IronRuby project in VS2010 into DLL/exe file?

Tags: compiler-construction, ironruby

After created IronRuby project in VS2010 by using IronRuby v1.1.x, I was able to use almost .NET library by importing them. But can't actually compile ironruby into exe/DLL.
I see the build option but can't build any exe or DLL from IronRuby project. Please help !

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561509/how-do-i-create-a-net-assembly-in-ironpython-and-call-it-from-c .  (Not a strict duplicate, but the answer is the same.)

Comment: But still no clue on how to compile this into .NET assembly ? And this time is in IronRuby not IronPython.

Comment: That's because it's not possible per se.  And it doesn't matter; you can't do this because both IronRuby and IronPython use the DLR.  The actual language doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compile your IronRuby classes into a .NET assembly and then access them from another assembly.

Preet is right that the nearest you can get is to embed your IronRuby scripts in (say) a C# assembly. From the C# side it would then be possible to instantiate your Ruby classes. So given the following Ruby class:

```rb
class HelloWorld
  def say_hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end
end
```

You could load this from a resource file and run it from C#:

```cs
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime;
using IronRuby;

var runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();
var engine = runtime.GetEngine("ruby");

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PathToResource.test.rb");
string code = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();

var scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.Execute(code, scope);

dynamic helloWorldClass = engine.Runtime.Globals.GetVariable("HelloWorld");
dynamic ironRubyObject = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(helloWorldClass);
ironRubyObject.say_hello();
```

Comment: It would be great if Visual Studio could compile IronRuby code to an EXE.

Answer (score 5):

There's a great IronRuby gem that packages IronRuby files into a Windows executable.

https://github.com/kumaryu/irpack

To use:

```
igem install irpack
irpack -o Program.exe Program.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Iron Ruby is simply DLR based code. You should be able to add the code into a resource of any assembly. Ultimately you'll need a bootstrap to load the code. That will most likely be a CLR language.

Comment: Does that mean I must get IronRuby source code and linking it with my Ruby project and compile it using .NET ?