# Create COM server with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, winapi, com, ole, com-server

Ruby on Windows has the win32::ole library that allows Ruby to act as a COM client, similar to VBScript and other scripting languages (Python, Perl, etc. with win32 bindings). However, I am wondering if it is possible to create a COM server with Ruby that can be accessed from other clients. Python makes this possible, even simple, with its win32 package, but I have not been able to find any examples of this with Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's always Python, which makes creating COM servers trivially easy. I'm giving up on Ruby for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Turns out that there is a way, as @Kevin Walzer points out in a followup comment. See below.

---

No.

The long answer is you can create a C# wrapper which delegates the work to IronRuby. See this question:

[Can I compile IronRuby project in VS2010 into DLL/exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191119/)

This resource might help also.

https://github.com/rifraf/IronRubyEmbeddedApps

Comment: After posting here, I ran across the rubycom library, archived here: [link](http://www.reocities.com/masonralph/ruby.html) and with documentation here: [link](http://reocities.com/SiliconValley/park/6558/rubycomdoc.html). By way of comparison, how widely used is IronRuby vs. standard Ruby on Windows?

Comment: Caveat: The download has a ten-year-old DLL but no source code. I'm wary of using a library with no source available. Hopefully the developer of the library still has his code archived somewhere.